# Java 6: why define generic twice?

Tags: java

What "Bad Things(tm)" happen when a generic is NOT defined twice in Java 6?

`List<String> foo = new ArrayList();`

instead of

`List<String> foo = new ArrayList<String>();`

since both compile fine, in my experience, and run fine as well.

In Java 7, one can use the diamond operator to avoid this entirely.

`List<String> foo = new ArrayList<>();`

This follows the DRY principle more closely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What "Bad Things(tm)" happen when a generic is NOT defined twice in
>   Java 6?

Probably nothing bad in case of default no-args constructor, as is the case with ArrayList, but what if there is a list constructor that takes one generic parameter, e.g.

```
class MyList<T> implements List<T>
{
  T firstValue;

  public MyList( T value )
  {
     firstValue = value;
  }
}

Apple apple = new Apple( );

// This compiles fine, and now we have a problem
// Hence the warning
MyList<Orange> foo = new MyList( apple );

// This does not compile
MyList<Orange> foo = new MyList<Apple>( apple );

// Nor this in Java 7
MyList<Orange> foo = new MyList<>( apple );
```

Answer (score 6):

The DRY principle is important, but there's also a principle of "Don't leave code in your project that generates warnings". Even if you understand the cause completely and know it to be completely harmless, it's a good habit to eliminate warnings.

The line

```
List<String> foo = new ArrayList();
```

compiles but generates a compiler warning, unless you annotate it with @SuppressWarnings. Generally it's less trouble to write it as

```
List<String> foo = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and live with the duplication. Or better, upgrade to JDK7 or later.

How I weigh the relative importance of these two principles depends on the case. DRY violations that extend to different parts of the code or into different files get intolerable quickly, but here the DRY violation is confined to a single line. There is some nuisance value when typing, but having warnings seems like a bigger nuisance, and a bad precedent to set.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a syntax, java doesn't know anything about generic types of your collection when you run your program.

All tips/checks about generics are happening in compile time. If you first declare your variable like

```
List<String> foo;
```

and then initialize it like

```
foo = new ArrayList();
```

You'll get a warning cause compiler have a suspicion that you forgot about declared generic type of your `foo`. Initialization with explicit generic type assures compiler that you remember everything ok.

Yes, it's too wordy, that's why it was replaced to diamond operator <> in Java 7. Nothing special.